# SSIS Convert Between Unicode and Non-Unicode Error with LARGE Field

Tags: ssis

I have been struggling with this error now for days now and have tried everything I know. I have an SQL statement that pulls data from several tables into another table. The field in question is a NTEXT field from a SQL 2000 database, which I now import into a SQL 2008 R2 table that is NVARCHAR(MAX) data type because I though the issue was the NTEXT data type. However the SSIS package that is just an OLE DB Source (with 1 field) into an Excel Destination is still giving me the Unicode and Non-Unicode Error!! Several rows of data are over 8000 characters in length. Please help ...

Comment: check the datatype on your Excel destination column.  It is likely that it is a non-unicode format.

Comment: No luck either. I followed these instructions to make the Excel destination UNICODE but I still got the same error. https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/article/link/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16

Comment: That link shows you how to save a file as UTF8 but what version of SQL server are you using?  UTF8 isn't supported till 2016.  Latin1 such as in  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation is windows 1252.

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008R2. I'm getting this error just trying to export a VARCHAR(MAX) with any length to Excel 2010 xlsx file.

Comment: Can you post the exact error?  What is the encoding of the Excel file?  If the File is UTF8 that is not supported.  What is your goal?  Are you trying to maintain latin characters in an export to Excel? Or is it really CSV (this was format of your link above)? Note Excel will open a CSV but it is not an Excel file.  Sample Data?

Comment: Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [635]]: Column "EnglishDescription" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "OLE DB Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

Comment: My goal is to export the NVARCHAR(MAX) field to any excel file or csv file. So far I have not been successful in doing this. No Latin involved at all. I think that SSIS just cannot handle this data type as it can be any length! It has to be NVARCHAR(MAX) as some records are over 8000 characters long and NVARCHAR has a Max of 8000 so I cant truncate it.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic349843-148-1.aspx has some thoughts and discussed MEMO and DT_NTEXT, If special characters are not present VARCHAR(MAX) instead it will reduce size.  Excel has a limit that you might reach so going with CSV might be better.  I will have to setup some example/test for me to help further sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The only way that have been able to do this is to paste the large Text into the 2nd row of the column that is to contain the String that is over 8000 characters. Then the package runs successfully. However this is not ideal because I don't want to have to delete that row manually, unless that can be done via a SSIS Task. There must be a way to create a Worksheet with the correct Data Type. I have tried MEMO and LONGTEXT and neither work. I'm still looking for an answer. I think my conclusion is that SSIS has hit a limit or I don't know the correct Excel Data Type to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of pain I finally came to the conclusion that Exporting to EXCEL is not possible so I turned to CSV. I used "Flat File Destination" object, pointed to a CSV that I had created with just the Headers. The Text Qualifier was set to double quotes. In the Columns section I set the Row delimiter to {CR}{LF} and the Column delimiter to Comma{,} because it is a CSV! The final part of the puzzle was to remove and double quotes, Carriage Returns and Line Feeds. I also had to convert the NTEXT field to VARCHAR(MAX) because REPLACE will not work with NTEXT. This is what I ended up with for the columns that had these "invalid characters".

REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),[MyNTEXTColumn]), CHAR(13),' '), '"', ''), CHAR(10),'') AS 'Corrected Output'

I replaced {CR} CHAR(13) with a space to that we could have it formatted well for the consumer. I hope this helps someone out one day.